# Unsetting kendoui child widget values when parent widget experiences a change event

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-combobox, kendo-ui-mvc

I have parent & child combobox widgets that are initialized with values. I specify "initialized with values" because I have no issues when I'm dealing with parent & child widgets that are initialized without any values.

Here's the parent widget initialization code:

```
var jsonObj = GetSavedJSONObject(key);
        var value = (jsonObj) ? '' + jsonObj.Id : '';
        var text = (jsonObj) ? '' + jsonObj.Name : '';
        $("#" + key).kendoComboBox({
            placeholder: placeholder,
            dataTextField: dataText,
            dataValueField: dataValue,
            filter: "contains",
            autoBind: false,
            enable: canEditAll,
            dataSource: {
                type: "jsonp",
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: urlValue,
                        type: "POST"
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            },
            value : value,
            text : text,
            select: selectEvent,
            change: changeEvent
        });
```

Here's the child widget initialization code:

```
var jsonObj = GetSavedJSONObject(key);
        var value = (jsonObj) ? '' + jsonObj.Id : '';
        var text = (jsonObj) ? '' + jsonObj.Name : '';
        $("#" + key).kendoComboBox({
            placeholder: placeholder,
            cascadeFrom: cascadeFromId,
            dataTextField: dataText,
            dataValueField: dataValue,
            filter: "contains",
            autoBind: false,
            delay: 300,
            enable: canEditAll,
            dataSource: {
                type: "jsonp",
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: urlValue,
                        data: getRateTypeSelected,
                        type: "POST"
                    }
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            },
            value : value,
            text : text,
            select: selectEvent2,
            change: changeEvent2
        });
```

In the *parent*'s select event, I'm doing this:

```
var childCombobox = $("#childWidget").data("kendoComboBox");
            if (childCombobox ) {  
                //setting parent value here
                e.sender.value(dataItem.Id);
                //should unset/clear the child widget per docs
                childCombobox.value(null);
                childCombobox.dataSource.read();
                if ($"#parentWidget").val()){
                    childCombobox.enable(true);
                }else{
                    childCombobox.enable(false);
                }
                console.log(childCombobox.value());
                console.log(childCombobox.text());
                console.log(childCombobox.input.val());
                console.log($("#childWidget").val());
                console.log(childCombobox);
            }
```

From the documentation I've seen, doing this:

```
combobox .value(null);
```

should have been sufficient to clear the selection from the child widget. The printouts in the console during execution show that the values are "". However, in the UI, I'm still seeing the old values of the child widget displayed. So if the old dataText of the child widget was "Tokyo" with a dataValue of 3, I would see the value "3" displayed in the child widget. Any points will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have the cascading property set then $("#child").value(""); and $("#child")..trigger('change'); should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for the Select event:

"The event is not fired when an item is selected programmatically."

They say to use the Cascade event:

"Fired when the value of the widget is changed via API or user interaction."

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#events-cascade